# Getting an error on NPM install request

Tags: node.js, rest, request, sails.js

When I execute `npm install request --save` I get the following error:

> NOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/rebeckaarieli/Documents/bd4s/nw-bd4s/node_modules/request' -> '/Users/rebeckaarieli/Documents/bd4s/nw-bd4s/node_modules/.request.DELETE

Comment: You can try deleting the request folder from node_modules, it might fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following commands, after you've verified that the existing request folder doesn't contain anything you've created and was actually saved in the wrong folder:

```
npm remove request
npm i --save request
```